# Is it possible to pass a function receiving self as a parameter of a function of self?

Tags: rust

Can I pass a function of an instance as a parameter to a function of the same instance, or do I have to pull the passed function out of the instance?

So, basically, does something like this work:

```
struct Some_Type {
}

impl Some_Type {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Some_Type{}
    }

    fn some_fn(&self, value: u32) -> u32 {
        value
    }

    fn some_other_fn(&self, value: u32, input_fn: &dyn Fn(&Self, u32) -> u32) -> u32 {
        input_fn(self, value)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let instance = Some_Type::new();
    let fourty_two = instance.some_other_fn(42, &instance.some_fn);
}
```

Or do I have to write it like this:

```
struct Some_Type {
}

impl Some_Type {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Some_Type{}
    }

    fn some_other_fn(&self, value: u32, fn: &dyn Fn(&Self, u32) -> u32) -> u32 {
        fn(value)
    }
}

fn some_fn(&Some_Type, value: u32) -> u32 {
    value
}

fn main() {
    let instance = Some_Type::new();
    let fourty_two = instance.some_other_fn(42, &some_fn);
}
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer - it's easier for the next person with this question to find it :)

Comment: This question has a number of issues not related to your problem: `Some_Type` and `new()` not declared, the parameter `fn` is a function that takes in 2 arguments but you're passing one (it'd need to be `fn(self, value)`, the parameter cannot be named `fn` because it is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. One can write

```
fn main() {
    let instance = Some_Type::new();
    let fourty_two = instance.some_other_fn(42, &Some_Type::some_fn);
}
```

and pass `&self` to `fn` inside `Some_Type.some_other_fn` in the first example.

Comment: Even with fixing the problems I mentioned above, this doesn't work: `Some_Type.some_fn` yields a *"attempted to take value of method `some_fn` on type `Some_Type`"* error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e57c761ce1a2bc61d7d21bf56cb31d67)) or a *"expected value, found struct `Some_Type`"* error depending on how its defined. You're looking for `Some_Type::some_fn`

Comment: Right, thanks again @kmdreko, I mistyped.